# whole link created using attribute passing, not working.

Tags: jquery

Trying to create a link dynamically for some purpose

```
$('', {
   text: 'Click here!',
   href: 'http://www.example.com',
   title: 'Click to win'
   }).appendTo('body');
```

But this is not working ... anything wrong ?

http://jsfiddle.net/QJy6P/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the initial parameter to dynamically create your A link element:

```
$('<a/>', {
   text: 'Click here!',
   href: 'http://www.example.com',
   title: 'Click to win'
   }).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not selected the jquery option in the fiddle, also specify what are you creating `<a/>`

```
$(function(){
$('<a/>', {
   text: 'Click here!',
   href: 'http://www.example.com',
   title: 'Click to win'
   }).appendTo('body');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QJy6P/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
$('<a/>', {
   text: 'Click here!',
   href: 'http://www.example.com',
   title: 'Click to win'
   }).appendTo('body');
```